# How to determine if the time complexity is O(m + n) or O(Math.max(m, n))

Tags: java, performance, time, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was going over this code but I'm struggling to understand how it is O(m + n) instead of O(Math.max(m, n)). Or is O(m + n) under O(Math.max(m, n)) anyways?

```
 int i = 0, j = 0, res = 0;
    while (i < houses.length) {
        while (j < heaters.length - 1
            && Math.abs(heaters[j + 1] - houses[i]) <= Math.abs(heaters[j] - houses[i])) {
            j++;
        }
        res = Math.max(res, Math.abs(heaters[j] - houses[i]));
        i++;
    }
```

There's an example on CTCI where the function returns an n sized array. It says that the space complexity of log(n) due to stack calls is dwarfed when calculating big O since n > logn, resulting in O(n) overall. O(n + logn) isn't mentioned in this example (4.4 for those curious).

Any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: In simpler words, `m + n <= Math.Max(m,n) + Math.Max(m,n) = O(Math.Max(m,n))`; hence the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already guessed, under the **Big-O-Notation** it is both *the same*.

Both functions, `m + n` and `max(m, n)`, are elements of **the set** `O(m + n) = O(max(m, n)`.

---

Let's do the math:

`m + n <= max(m, n) + max(m, n) = 2 * max(m, n)` and also
`max(m, n) <= m + n` as long as `min(m, n) >= 0` (however `m, n >= 0` already)

So both functions are bounded by the other function (plus a constant factor), hence `O(m + n)` or `O(max(m, n))`, the sets are equal.

Here is the formal (*1-dimensional*) definition (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)):

[image: Definition of O-Notation]

---

Intuitively it also *makes sense* as both functions just mean **linear growth in both variables** and nothing more.

---

> [...] resulting in O(n) overall. O(n + logn) isn't mentioned [...]

I am unsure whether that is a question. Just note that both sets are again the same as `n <= n + log(n)` and also `n + log(n) <= n + n = 2 * n`, **linear in n**.